# How to update DataFileInformation Table using ODBC

Tags: myob

I need to ask you that can i update DataFileInformation  table using ODBC in MYOB. I have searched their document but not find any information regarding that.

Thanks
Nasir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataFileInformation table is read-only, so no you can't alter company file settings or company information using the ODBC driver. The version of MYOB you are targeting runs an ISAM database, so the functionality that the ODBC driver exposes is really a set of virtual mappings or services.